# Keras Tuple Index out of Range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try training my model at the end of the first epoch I get an index error, I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it?

> Epoch 1/10 429/430 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss:
> 3.0401e-07 - accuracy: 0.2926
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 7             epochs=10,
> 8             validation_data=('X_val','y_val'),
> ----> 9             callbacks=callbacks
> 10             )
>
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py
> in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
> 65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
> 66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
> ---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> 68     finally:
> 69       del filtered_tb
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py
> in **getitem**(self, key)
> 907       else:
> 908         if self._v2_behavior:
> --> 909           return self._dims[key]
> 910         else:
> 911           return self.dims[key]
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Code

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
processed_inputs = text_vectorization(inputs)
embedded = layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_tokens, output_dim=256, mask_zero=True)(processed_inputs)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(embedded)
x = layers.Dense(16,activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks = [keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="test", 
                                             save_best_only=True, 
                                             monitor="val_loss",), 
             keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuracy", patience=5)]


history = model.fit(
            X_train,
            y_train,
            epochs=10,
            validation_data=('X_val','y_val'),
            callbacks=callbacks
            )
```

Comment: what's the shape of `x_train` and `y_train`

Comment: What is validation_data=('X_val','y_val') supposed to do?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the shape of both is (13733,)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, as I understand it (quite new to this) this allows history to also track how the model performs on validation data. Callbacks can then find the best model performance from this validation

Comment: @ChrisH maybe better to pass the variable instead of a string...

Comment: I mean that you are passing strings, not actual variables, might be the problem.

Comment: How does one go about passing the variables instead?

Comment: Without the single quotes. (X_val,y_val)